# p:dataTable selected row always null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am basing my example on the PrimeFaces showcase example for the `p:dataTable`ContextMenu [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml)

The difference being I am trying to delete via a `p:confirmDialog` but the selected item is always null.

Here's a cut down example

The XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Example</title>s
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="cd" severity="alert" header="Confirmation"
            message="Are you sure you wish to delete this car?">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{carTableView.deleteCar}"
                update=":dataForm" oncomplete="PF('cd').hide();" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="PF('cd').hide();" type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="dataForm">
        <p:contextMenu for="cars">
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"
                onclick="PF('cd').show(); return false;" />
            <!--    action="#{formsView.deleteForm}" update=":dataForm" /> -->
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{carTableView.cars}"
            rowKey="#{car.id}" selection="#{carTableView.selectedCar}"
            selectionMode="single">
            <f:facet name="header">
                            RightClick to View Options
                        </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The Model

```
public class Car
{

    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Car(String id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And the bean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CarTableView implements Serializable
{

    private List<Car> cars;

    private Car selectedCar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        cars = createCars();
    }

    private List<Car> createCars()
    {
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Car(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), "Car " + String.valueOf(i + 1)));
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void deleteCar()
    {
        cars.remove(selectedCar);
        selectedCar = null;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars()
    {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars)
    {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar()
    {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar)
    {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

}
```

Now it seems to me that it's the involvement of running the `deleteCar` action from the `p:confirmDialog` that is the issue.

I say this as if I change

```
<p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"
        onclick="PF('cd').show(); return false;" />
```

To

```
<p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"
        action="#{formsView.deleteForm}" update=":dataForm" />
```

Then it works. In the `p:confirmDialog` example the `selectedCar` in the deleteCar method is always null. Despite specifying a `rowKey` attribute in `p:dataTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: The `p:confirmDialog` needs to be part of the same `h:form` as the `p:dataTable`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two forms, enclose `<h:setPropertyActionListener >` to  your `<p:menuitem>`